# Determine whether this polynomial is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Consider the polynomial $$ f = 2x+1 $$

I need to determine whether this polynomial is a unit (invertible element) in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$.

If it were a unit in this ring, then there would have to exist a polynomial of the form $ax+b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ such that $$ \displaystyle (2x+1)(ax+b) = 1_{\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]} $$

To that effect, I supposed that such a polynomial existed, and multiplied out $$ (2x+1)(ax+b) = 2ax^{2}+(2b+a)x + b = 1$$

Then, I solved the following system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$:
$$ 2a = 0 \quad (1) $$
$$ a + 2b = 0 \quad (2) $$
$$ b = 1 \quad (3) $$

Supposing that equation $(3)$ holds, I substituted $b = 1$ into equation $(2)$, and got that $a = 3$. But, then if $a=3$, $2a = 1 \neq 0$, so that $(1)$ does not hold.

Therefore, the system of equations is inconsistent in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, and so we can find no such $ax+b$, which in turn, implies that $2x+1$ is not a unit.

**I was wondering if this is the correct way to approach this problem and if I have successfully proven what I set out to prove, which was that $f = 2x+1$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.**

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: It's a general result that for a ring $R$ the units in $R[x]$ are precisely the units of $R$.

Comment: Why would the inverse have to be of degree 1 or less?

Comment: @ThePuix Only if $R$ doesn't have zero divisors.

Comment: @ALannister: Note that there's no justification for your assumption that other factor has degree $1$, so your argument is not correct. Instead, use the argument given by Tsemo Aristide which allows the other factor to have an arbitrary degree.

Comment: In the ring $(\Bbb Z/(4))[x]$, you get $(1+2x)^2=1$. If a ring $R$ *has no nilpotent elements*, then $(R[x])^\times=R^\times$.

Comment: @ThePuix this is not true at all, look at $R=\Bbb Z/4[x]$ then $2x+1$ is a unit with inverse $1-2x (=2x+1)$ which is clearly not a unit of $R$.

Comment: @Lubin great minds! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field, so if $q(x)=a_0+...+a_nx^n\neq 0, a_n\neq 0$, the leading coefficient of $(2x+1)q(x)=2a_n\neq 0$ and is associated to $x^{n+1}$. So the degree of $(2x+1)q(x)$ is strictly superior to $0$ and $2x+1$ is not a unit.

Answer (score 4):

$Z_5$ is a field therefore $Z_5[x]$ is an integral domain.

Hence, $\deg fg = \deg f + \deg g$.

What can you conclude from here?